# Using ngResource in an AngularJS SPA

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest, ngresource

I am using ngResource in a factory to fetch data from a REST API URL, and then do some basic processing on the retrieved data. This works fine (verified using `console.log()`). I injected the dependencies properly in my root module and in the main controller, and set a `$scope` variable equal to this retrieved data.

In HTML, I put `{{variableName}}` inside the desired tag.
However, it doesn't get populated.

What am I missing? Do I need to add `$watch` or something else in order for this to work?

PS -

`var dataResource = $resource("http://<URL>");
 $scope.trialData = dataResource.get();`

This `trialData` populates values from the same URL just fine when I add this directly to the controller.

Comment: It's tricky to say the exact problem without seeing a complete example with the html template and controller. Initially `$scope.trialData` will be an empty object, but when the `get()` completes it will be populated. You say you use `controllerName.variableName` but your code is accessing the scope as `$scope` so you won't have a controller name.

Comment: @Duncan Sorry, that was an oversight in my attempt to simplify the problem. Correction made.

Answer (score 0):

Resources use asynchronous request. You have to wait for their promise to be resolved like this :

```
dataResource.get().$promise.then(function(object){
   $scope.trialData = object;// or maybe object.data
});
```

Comment: Must I do this inside the factory? Currently, I am using the factory to return the value but assigning it to a `$scope` variable inside the controller.

Comment: nop this is not how promise works. If you do return dataResource.get() on your factory. Then you should use the $promise fields in your controller. You should take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/ng/service/$q to understand how promises works.

Comment: One more thing, if you use controllerAs syntax, use this instead of $scope.