# AngularJS, apply changes to the view from the factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to display error messages from $exceptionHandler factory with a lifespan of 5 seconds. So I have a view with the following code

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="message" ng-repeat="message in errors">
         {{message}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and factory

```
services.factory('$exceptionHandler',function ($injector) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
        var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $rootScope.errors = $rootScope.errors || [];
        $rootScope.errors.push(exception.message);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $rootScope.errors.splice(0,1);
        }, 5000);
    };
});
```

The messages were displayed fine, but after removing them from array, they are still present on view. I think I need to do something with $digest and $apply, but I don't understand what. Need help!

Comment: Inserting any scope into a service is quite bad practice though :(

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Depends, if it's the service's purpose, like displaying errors, i don't see anything wrong with it. A more clean solution would be to define a service that stores and expire messages and to have an independant  controller (binded with ng-controller) that watch for the current messagesand display them, this is what i have :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `setTimeout` when you should be using angular's `$timeout` service.

When the callback is triggered by `setTimeout` angular doesn't know that it has to refresh the html. If you use `$timeout` instead then it will know to rtun a digest loop after the callback has completed and your page should update correctly.

You could also explicitly trigger the digest loop from inside the callback, sometimes you have to do that, but for timeouts just use the service provided.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340014/using-ngresource-in-an-angularjs-spa) using factory, but that is independent of $timeout. Could you please take a look?
Thanks!

Comment: @SauhardGupta, didn't get why it's similar

Comment: i have changed to the $timeout. There is result:
Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- $timeout <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope

Comment: @Виталий Захаров then use $injector.get('$timeout');