# Angular. How can i display error from exception handler on view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to catch, customize and display all my errors and exception on view in my application. So i'm trying to find best ways to do that. Few days ago i asked this question [AngularJS, apply changes to the view from the factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340195/angularjs-apply-changes-to-the-view-from-the-factory). And everything worked fine until i got a problem with injections. So i try to find best solution for displaying errors on view from factory.

now i have a view

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="message" ng-repeat="message in errors" ng-bind="message"></div>
</div>
```

and factory

```
services.factory('$exceptionHandler',['$injector', function ($injector) {
    return function(exception, cause){
        var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        var $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        var message;

        $rootScope.errors = $rootScope.errors || [];
        switch (exception.message){
            case 'Unexpected token A':
                message = 'Connection problem';
                break;
            default:
                message = exception.message;
        }

        $rootScope.errors.push(message);
        $timeout(function(){
            $rootScope.errors.splice(0,1);
        }, 5000);
    };
}]);
```

and i'm trying to get rid off inserting scope into service.
So how can i get all my exceptions in controller to displaying their on view?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `applicationErrors` service like this:

```
angular.module('YourModule').factory('applicationErrors', function() {
   var errors = [];

   return {
      errors: errors
   };
});
```

Then get rid of `$timeout` and `$rootScope` in your exception handler, and use this service to keep track of the errors. You can inject it into your controller and that's how your view will get access to the errors.

One important thing to note though is that you will need to be careful to not overwrite array in the `applicationErrors`. I imagine you'll probably want to use it like this:

```
angular.module('YourModule').controller('YourController', ['applicationErrors', function(applicationErrors) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.errors = applicationErrors.errors;
}]);
```

If you overwrite `applicationErrors.errors` with a new array, `vm.errors` will still be pointing to the previous array. So if you ever want to clear it, do it this way:

```
applicationErrors.errors.length = 0;
```

or... just make it a method on your service:

```
angular.module('YourModule').factory('applicationErrors', function() {
   var errors = [];

   function clear() {
      errors.length = 0;
   }

   return {
      errors: errors,
      clear: clear
   };
});
```